How to change the kernel stack size for the kernel modules in Ubuntu 14.04?
I want to change the kernel stack size of Ubuntu 14.04 for the kernel modules. However, with menuconfig, or .config I couldn't find the CONFIG_THREAD_STACK_SIZE option.
I just want to increase the kernel stack size for my kernel modules which use callbacks each other.
What can I do?

It's unclear what you want to do and why... Ubuntu 14.04 is out of support since 2019.

The first thing you'll want to do is upgrade your system to a version that didn't EOL five years ago. It's entirely possible that the kernel that that release uses simply doesn't have the option yet.

That CONFIG_THREAD_STACK_SIZE (or just THREAD_STACK_SIZE) just doesn't exist – especially not in the 3.13 kernel used by Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.
So, I don't know where you have that name from, but it's wrong.
When you read the kernel documentation on the topic, https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/next/x86/kernel-stacks.html , you'll notice that stack size (STACK_SIZE) is not a configuration option.
You simply can't change it; you would have to change its definition in all these 35 place: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.13/A/ident/THREAD_SIZE and then fix all the code that makes implicit assumptions on it.
Generally, increasing stack size to enable callbacks sounds like you're trying to hide a bug, to be completely honest. Twice the page size is actually not that little stack! (it's only 8 kB on a kernel this ancient, but you can allocate and free memory as needed, and if you're doing callbacks to a degree where this becomes impossible, then you should rethink your architecture, probably – you're thrashing the I-caches of your CPU. If you have to do very deeply nested callbacks, then you might want to look into how other kernel modules use lock-free (or low-overhead) work queues to communicate workload items between tasklets. That has the distinct advantage that your code gets the ability to cooperate more nicely on a machine that has high CPU load. It's a case-by-case decision, but I'd say the fact that you're getting so deep into nested callbacks that your stack outgrows its allocated size is a strong indication you're trying to use a userland scripting language paradigm in the kernel space, which might work out to be more complicated than expected.
Also, as mentioned in the comments: Ubuntu 14.04 is end-of-life. If you're developing on kernel things, you should pressure whoever is responsible for your environment to allow you to use a modern operating system.
